# Any way to save values in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a very simple replicate function that takes a LIST of numbers and returns a list with each number duplicated. The replicate function that takes a value and an element is more trivial to me, since it doesn't require saving state.

But in Haskell, I got this so far:

```
> replicate' [] = []
> replicate' (x:xs)
>           | x == 1    = x: replicate' xs
>           | otherwise = x: replicate'(x-1:xs)
```

which is obviously wrong, since for `replicate' [2,2]`, it'd print `[2,1,2,1]` instead of `[2,2,2,2]`

I know I have to save x into some other variable and decrement it but I don't believe I know the syntax for that.

Whoops, people got a little confused with the question.

For example, a call `replicate' [2,3,1]`, should return `[2,2,3,3,3,1]`, not just `[2,2,3,3,1,1]`, like I think you guys are thinking

Comment: Writing your problem clearly is a good first step to solving it. For instance:  "`replicate'` on a list `(x:xs)` is (the number `x` at the head of the list, repeated `x` times) prepended to (the tail of the list `replicate'`-ed)". If we state the problem in a _declarative_ way (by describing what our functions _are_) we end up with something we can translate directly into haskell (replace "is" with `=`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
replicate' [] = []
replicate' (x:xs) = x:x:replicate' xs
```

You can simply add two items immediately.

```
*Main> replicate' [1,2,3]
[1,1,2,2,3,3]
```

**UPD:**

```
duplicate::Int->Int->[Int]
duplicate 0 x = []
duplicate n x = x:duplicate (n-1) x

replicate' [] = []
replicate' (x:xs) = duplicate x x ++(replicate' xs)
```

Comment: It's not double them, it depends on the variable. Like `replicate' [1,2,3]` would output `[1,2,2,3,3,3]`

Comment: @ig-melnyk Your `duplicate` function is equivalent to `replicate` (from the Prelude).

Comment: @Jubobs sure, I know. I think in that assignment it's not supposed to use library functions

Comment: Ugh, why didn't I think of that? Thank you

Answer (score 5):

> I know I have to save x into some other variable

No, you don't.  This sentence indicates you have some misunderstanding.  I suggest you think about why you believe this is true and fix that understanding.

As for your problem you have a good start showing you know about recursion, base cases, and basic syntax. Nice work.  The code you provided was:

```
replicate' [] = []
replicate' (x:xs)
          | x == 1    = x: replicate' xs
          | otherwise = x: replicate'(x-1:xs)
```

The base case is good, but why are you subtracting one from x? and why does it appear (again) in the replicate call?  Just think about the operation you want, there is no need for any arithmetic on the elements - you want to construct a list that repeats every element and the syntax is like `newelement : rest` - we can read `:` as "cons".  So your second case should be:

```
replicate' (x:xs) = x : x : replicate' xs
```

Edit again, since you've clarified that the elements are numbers that indicate how many times they must appear.  Well, the obvious solution is to use replicate (from base) as part of `replicate'`:

```
replicate' [] = []
replicate' (x:xs) = replicate x x ++ replicate' xs
```

In the above we replicate each element the number of times equal to the value of the element then concatenate that list, via `++`, to the recursive call.  A simpler version is:

```
replicate' = concatMap (\x -> replicate x x)
```

For example:

```
Prelude> concatMap (\x -> replicate x x) [1..3]
[1,2,2,3,3,3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your logic (but poor example) I'm guessing you want to repeat each element as many times the value indicates (`[2,3] -> [2,2,3,3,3]`).

You can write a `repeat'` function as `repeat' n = take n $ repeat n` and use in your replicate function

```
replicate' :: [Int] -> [Int]
replicate' [] = []
replicate' (x:xs) = repeat' x ++ replicate' xs
```

UPDATE:

You can write a repeat' function recursively as well, you need to use an auxiliary function to carry the additional count information.  Something like this should work

```
 rep :: Int -> [Int]
 rep x = rep' x x
   where rep' x 0 = []
         rep' x n = x: rep' x (n-1)
```

here instead of saving the state (count) you pass as a decreasing argument, similar to a loop count.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, but for my assignment I don't know if we're allowed to use `take` or `repeat`. Is it possible to rewrite them in a recursive form maybe? It specifically says "You may use a nested helper definition"
Works perfect btw

Comment: You could replace `repeat' n` by `replicate n n`. However, you might want to make the "concatenate vanish", for better efficiency.